# how to await value from another await variable

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I cannot figure out how should I construct my code.

Basic info:

webhook (intercom) --> google cloud functions (await values) --> post message to slack.

Issue:

My code is working fine until I need to get an value from another await function and I am not sure how should I 'pause' the second await until the first one is complete.

Code:

```
// first function to get the information about agent
const getTeammateInfo = async function (teammate_id) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get("https://api.intercom.io/admins/" + teammate_id, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': "Bearer " + INTERCOM_API_AUTH_TOKEN,
        'Content-type': "application/json",
        'Accept': "application/json"
      }
    });
    const { data } = response
    return data
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

// second function, which needs values from first function in order to find data
const slackID = async function (slack_email) {
  if (slackID) {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("https://api.intercom.io/admins/" + slack_email, {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': "Bearer " + SLACK_API_TOKEN,
          'Content-type': "application/json",
          'Accept': "application/json"
        }
      });
      const { user } = response
      return user
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
};
```

It is used within the Google Cloud Function (

```
exports.execute = async (req, res) => {
  try {

    // map of req from intercom webhook
    let {
      data: {
        item: {
          conversation_rating: {
            rating,
            remark,
            contact: {
              id: customerId
            },
            teammate: {
              id: teammateId
            }
          }
        }
      }

    } = req.body

  const teammateName = await getTeammateInfo(teammateId); // this works fine
  const slackTeammateId = await slackID(teammateName.email) // this is where it fails I need to get the values from 'teammateName' in order for the function slackID to work


  ...

 } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    res.status(500)
    res.json({ error: error })
  }

}
```

I have tried with Promise.all

```
const [teammateName, slackTeammateId] = await Promise.all([
  getTeammateInfo(teammateId), 
  slackID(teammateName.email)
])
```

But I just cannot wrap my head around this how it should work.

Thank you.

// edit:

Code is okay, I just put the wrong API into the slackID function...
Thanks for double checking.

Comment: Can't immediately see the issue with the async code. So have you checked if `teammateName ` actually contains the property email? What does ` const teammateName` look like when the first promise resolves?

Comment: You can't use `Promise.all()` for this, since it runs both calls concurrently, without dependencies. The variables don't get set until both calls return.

Comment: await `getTeammateInfo`, get data the result and await  `slackID` looks like what you should be doing.  Promise all is not right, since one relies on the other.  The debugging job here is probably not about the async logic.  The question is what's wrong with slackId()?  Unit test it by passing a hard-coded param that you know should work

Comment: `I am not sure how should I 'pause' the second await until the first one is complete.` Await does this for you.  So this is not your problem.

Comment: I feel stupid.

You guys were right, I had wrong value in the slackID, had IntercomAPI there. The await works great, I was bashing my head around and questioned if I really know how await works. 

Then I was trying with Promise which I knew wont do it, but it was a last resort. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with `Promise.all()` is that it fires both functions at the same time and waits until both are done, so you can't chain that way.

```js
let teammateName
let slackTeammateId
getTeammateInfo(teammateId).then(r => {
   teammateName = r
   slackID(teammateName.email).then(r2 => {  
      slackTeammateId = r2  
   )}  
);
```

`then()` method, on the other hand, waits until your method's return and then fires out everything in the callback function.

Comment: Thanks Artur, the 'await' in my initial solution worked okay, I had just wrong API set.

Buut this solution is also a slick one I will probably use somewhere in the future. 

Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help you :)